# Вопрос по структуре классов ООП

Tags: php, ооп, классы

Существует несколько видов работников: программист, дизайнер, тестировщик, менеджер . Есть разные виды работ: 
1) писать код, 
2) тестировать код, 
3)общаться с менеджером, 
4) рисовать, 
5)ставить задачи. 
Каждый из работников может выполнять определенную работу, к примеру программист может выполнять 1,2 и 3 виды работ, дизайнер в свою очередь 3,4, тестировщик - 2,3,5 и менеджер - 5. Нужно cоздать метод, который будет выводить виды работ которые может выполнять работник, к примеру

```
$developer = new Developer();
$developer->typeOfWork()
// на выходе получаем: 
// - code writing
// - code testing
// - communication with manager
```

и возможность проверить, может ли этот работник выполнять конкретную работу, например $developer->getWriteCode(); - вернет true. $developer->getDraw() - вернет false. 
  В своем решении я создал абстрактный класс Employee с 5ю защищенными переменными (видами работ) $writeCode, $draw и т.д., которые по умолчанию равны false. Также я создал методы, которые выводят значения этих защищенных свойств, getWriteCode() и т.д. и один метод для итерации свойств метода и вывода всех работ ( по типу typeOfWork() как я писал ранее) Далее я Наследую от этого Класса классы Самих работников, Developer, Designer и т.д, но в них я объявляю только свойства объекта, то есть виды работ, к примеру

```
class Developer extends Employee {
    protected $writeCode = 'code writing';
    protected $testingCode = 'code testing';
    protected $communicateWithManager = 'communication with manager';
}
```

Получается, что для вывода определенного свойства я обращаюсь к родительскому методу(то есть в классе Employee) и вывожу значения этого свойства. Собственно вопрос, насколько это корректная структура классов? Нормально ли создавать класс в котором объявлены только свойства(например, как в классе Developer), а все методы берутся с класса-родителя? Буду благодарен любому отзыву и мнению

Comment: вместо пяти свойств заведите массив с соответствующими ключами лучше

Comment: @teran спасибо за отзыв, а можете уточнить, почему будет лучше сделать именно массивом а не переменными?

Comment: А как вы определяете что может работник в базовом классе? Через property_exists? Базовый класс не должен ничего знать про дочерние свойства. В случае с массивом, можно определить пустой массив в базовом классе и анализировать его. Дочерние, в свою очередь, этот список переопределят. Я бы даже сделал абстрактный метод, который должен возвращать этот список.

Comment: @vp_arth абстрактный ли?

Comment: @vp_arth в базовом классе я просто перебирал свойства класса и если они были равны true (по умолчанию в базовом они false) то выводил их, таким образом: 
`foreach($this as $key => $value) {
 if($value) {
  return "$key => $value\n";
 }
 }` но в целом, скорее всего сделать массив с ключами и работать с ним будет все-таки более удобно

Comment: Это не ООП. Так делать можно только для объектов, суть которых - хранить некоторое состояние, так называемые DTO(Data Transfer Object). Перебирать свойства живого полиморфного объекта с некоторым поведением недопустимо - как мне добавить неитерируемое этим циклом свойство при наследовании от ваших классов?

Comment: @teran а нельзя ли создать 5 интерфейсов маркеров и на каждый класс вещать свои интерфейсы? А потом на них опираться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На мой взгляд можно сделать так: делаем интерфейсы, определяющие тип. Навешиваем эти маркеры на сотрудников. В родительском классе будет метод, который собирает все действия, которые может производить сотрудник. Примерно также можно определить и способен ли человек что-то сделать.

```
<?php
interface ICodeWriting {}
interface ICodeTesting {}
interface IDesigning {}
interface ICommunicationWithManager {}

abstract class Employee {        
    public function getTypesOfWork() {
        $types = '';

        if ($this instanceof ICodeWriting)
            $types .= "code writing \n";
        if ($this instanceof ICodeTesting)
            $types .= "code testing \n";
        if ($this instanceof IDesigning)
            $types .= "designing \n";
        if ($this instanceof ICommunicationWithManager)
            $types .= "communication with manager \n";

        return $types;
    }
}

class Developer extends Employee implements ICodeWriting, ICodeTesting, ICommunicationWithManager { }
class Designer extends Employee implements IDesigning, ICommunicationWithManager {}

echo "developer: \n";
$developer = new Developer();
echo $developer->getTypesOfWork();

echo "\n";

echo "designer: \n";
$designer = new Designer();
echo $designer->getTypesOfWork();
```

Вывод:

```
developer: 
code writing 
code testing 
communication with manager 

designer: 
designing 
communication with manager
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bc758b8ab1e825c102200c6ec4a51a7f3b5bea16

---

Еще можно с трейтами побаловаться и в них логику попрописывать и определять данные. И подключать к соответствующим классам. [Ссылка на доки про Трейты](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.traits.php)

Comment: основная проблема в том, что навыки эти потенциально могут расширяться. И что и в начальном коде автора, что тут требуется написание либо новых полей класса, либо создание новых интерфейсов и их явное указание. тем более еще явно перебирая их в базовом классе для вывода.

Comment: @teran да, знаю, Но вот тот же Роберт Мартин не стесняется и делает подобную штуку в своей книге. Правда он switch использовал и для того чтобы делать потомков (ибо это абстрактная фабрика получалась) - https://i.stack.imgur.com/rW1Mm.png. Там тоже потенциально могло всё расширяться. Но кмк здесь могло это найти место. И выглядит поприятнее и по ООП'шному что ли,нежели массив со свойствами. Ну еще можно трейты рассмотреть, как я написал